# What does mean the Chain Rule for Jacobians?

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems

Let $f : M \to M$ be a continuous endomorphism on the manifold $M$ and $\mu$ an $f$-invariant probability on $M$. Consider that there exists a measurable partition $\xi = \{A_0, A_1, ...\}$ such that $f$ is injective on each $A_i$ and the push-forward measure $((f|_{A_i})^{-1})_* \mu := \mu \; \circ \; f|_{A_i}$ is absolutely continuous on $A_i$ with respect to $\mu$. The respective Radon-Nikodym derivative will be called the $\textbf{Jacobian}$ of $\mu$ with respect to $f$:
$$J_f(\mu)(x) = \frac{d \mu \circ (f|_{A_i})}{d \mu}(x) \; \mu-a.e. on \; A_i, i \geq 0.$$

What does it mean the Chain Rule for Jacobians in this settings?

Thank you!

Comment: Practically, it is a product of matrices.